# How to improve node js code for production and split it properly across files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I'm new to javascript and node.js.

Can someone answer the following questions.
  1. How I split the PostgreSQL part properly in an other file.
  2. How I the pest practice is to use the pg pools.
  3. How I improve this code for production.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const pg = require('pg');
const pool = new pg.Pool({
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'test123!',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '5432',
    database: 'test_db'
});

app.get('/api/recipes', function(req, res){
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        if(err){
            console.log('Connection failed '+ err);
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM recipes;', function(err, result) {
            done();
            if(err){
                console.log('Error with query! ERROR code: ' + err.code);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            else{
                res.status(200).send(result.rows)
            }
        });
    });
});

app.get('/api/recipes/:id', function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        if(err){
            console.log('Connection failed ' + err);
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        else{
            client.query('SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE recipes_id = $1;', [id], function(err, result) {
                done();
                if(err){
                    console.log('Error with query! ERROR code: ' + err.code);
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.status(200).send(result.rows)
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('Server listen on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways folks go to split the code you've described.  I'll take it piece by piece.

First, pull any configurable variables out and setup one file that can get them from the environment (possibly with dev defaults in place, your choice on that).  You can use a library like [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) or [convict](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convict), but honestly I prefer to just write a simple file that pulls them myself:

```
// ./config.js
module.exports = {
  pool: {
      user: process.env.DB_USER || 'admin',
      password: process.env.DB_PW || 'test123!',
      host: process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
      port: process.env.DB_PORT || '5432',
      database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'test_db'
    }
};
```

As for your database calls, some folks like to use ORM-like stuff such as [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/), but again I tend to start simple and add things as needed.  In your case, you should think about what boilerplate stuff you can make common code around, and then wrap those into simple modules that only expose to the calling code stuff it really needs.  For example, you will note that most of your routes are going to connect to the pool, test for an error, then run a query if it doesn't error out, and finally render either the error or query results, right?  So that can all be wrapped into a fairly simple query function that handles the boilerplate internally and works with just a query expression and a callback, for example:

```
// ./db/index.js
const pg = require('pg');

const config = require('./config');
const pool = new pg.Pool(config.pool);

function query(sql, params, callback) {
   // maybe check for valid inputs here or something, but at least normalize in case folks don't pass params

  if(arguments.length < 3) {
     callback = params;
     params = null;
  }

   pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
       // just exit here and let the calling code know there was a problem
       if(err) return callback(err);

       // I haven't tested this w/ the pg library recently, you might have to do two of these if it doesn't like null as a second argument
       client.query(sql, params, (err, result) => {
          if(err) return callback(err);
          done();
          // calling code probably doesn't care about anything but rows, but you can do other stuff here if you prefer
          return callback(null, result.rows);
       });
   });
};

// You can also add additional functions if you want shorthand for doing things like query by ID or with params, or similar
module.exports = { query };
```

I also think that it can be helpful to store the SQL strings somewhere centrally, or on model objects, just to make the routing code note have to care about that.  For a super simple example using your two routes, I might do something like this:

```
// ./db/queries.js 
module.exports = {
  RECIPES: {
    LIST: 'SELECT * FROM recipes;',
    FIND_BY_ID: 'SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE recipes_id = $1;'
  }
};
```

Ok, so now your routing code can be quite simple, you can just get the db module and work the query, letting the routing worry just about what it's got to do with the request and response. Another option that folks like is to actually create a module for each model in your app (e.g. a Recipe) that wraps the above two files into a set of static functions so that your routes don't even know they're querying specifically.  The calls in that case would be something like `Recipe.list(cb)` or `Recipe.findById(id, cb)`.  This is a style made popular by Ruby on Rails a few years ago, it has mixed acceptance in the Node community, but I'm mentioning it for completeness.

```
// ./routes/recipes.js
const router = require('express').Router();
const db = require('./db');
const queries = require('./db/queries');

router.get('/api/recipes', (req, res, next) => {
  db.query(queries.RECIPES.LIST, (err, rows) => {
    if(err) return next(err);
    return res.send(rows); // status 200 is the default here
  });
});

router.get('/api/recipes/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  db.query(queries.RECIPES.FIND_BY_ID, [id], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.send(rows);
  });
});
```

Finally, in your main Express setup file:

```
// ./app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const recipeRoutes = require('./routes/recipes') // note if you have an index.js file that gets imported just by calling for the folder, so that's a way to group features as well

app.use(recipeRoutes);

// I'm a big fan of error handling middleware. There's a more complex approach I did in [praeter][4] that gives you http-verb based errors that you can then catch and send the appropriate status, but that's again more complex than you might need here. 

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // this can be as simple or as complex as you like.
  // note it's a best practice to send only "clean" messages to the client, so you don't give away that you're using a Postgres db or other stuff that makes hacking easier. 
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).send('Oops! Something went wrong!!');
});
```

Obviously, there's a lot of ways to skin this cat, so I'd recommend mostly just looking for where you're repeating yourself, and then refactor to repeat less.  Also, if you're interested in making more production-ready apps in general, the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) is a must-read.

Answer (score 0):

To answer number 1,

dbPool.js

```
const pg = require('pg');

export.pool = new pg.Pool({
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'test123!',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '5432',
    database: 'test_db'
});
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const pool = require('./dbPool');
....
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create config file and require that file in app.js

```
--config
    ----config.js
--app.js


var config = {
  production: {
    pool: {
      user: 'admin',
      password: 'test123!',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: '5432',
      database: 'test_db'
    }
  },
  development: {
    pool: {
      user: 'admin',
      password: 'test123!',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: '5432',
      database: 'test_db'
    }
  }
}

exports.get = function get(env) {
  return config[env] || config.development;
}
```